# $L^2$ convergence by the sequence of domain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be open bounded, smooth boundary. Assume $u\in L^\infty(\Omega)$. We know a sequence $u_n\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ such that 
$$
\sup_{n}\|u_n\|_{L^\infty}<+\infty
$$
and $u_n\to u$ in $L^2$ weakly.

Now, assume that for any $\Omega'\subset\subset \Omega$, i.e., compactly contained in, we have $u_n\to u$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega')$.

My question: can we deduce that $u_n\to u$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ as well? (up to a subsequence of course)

Comment: consider $K_n$ a sequence of compactly supported $\subset \Omega$ such that $||1||_{\Omega / K_n} \to 0$ and that $|| u_n-u||_{L^\infty}< C$ so that $||u_m-u||_{\Omega /K_n} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C = \sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \|u_n\|_\infty$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and $\Omega' \subset\subset \Omega$ so that $L^n(\Omega\setminus \Omega') <\epsilon$. Then

$$\|u_n\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \le \|u_n\|^2_{L^2(\Omega')} + C^2\epsilon.$$

Given that $u_n \to u$ strongly in $\Omega'$, we have

$$
\begin{split} 
\limsup_{n\to \infty} \|u_n\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} &\le \|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega')} + C^2\epsilon \\
&\le \|u\|^2_{L^2 (\Omega)} + C^2 \epsilon.
\end{split}$$

Let $\epsilon \to 0$, we have

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \|u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.$$

Together with

$$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \ge \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$

coming from the weak convergence $u_n\to u$, then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$

and so the convergence $u_n \to u$ is a strong convergence in $\Omega$.

Comment: From weak convergence, we get $\|u\|\leq \liminf_n \|u_n\|$. But you use the reverse estimate.

Comment: Ar ha! So careless, Thanks @PhoemueX